# py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o63.save. : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, hbase

I am new to Spark and BigData component - HBase, I am trying to write Python code in Pyspark and connect to HBase to read data from HBase. I'm using the following versions:

- Spark version: `spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7`
- Python version: `3.8.5`
- HBase version: `hbase-2.3.5`

I have installed standalone Hbase and Spark in my local on ubuntu 20.04

Code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlc = SQLContext(sc)

data_source_format = 'org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase'

df = sc.parallelize([("1","Abby","Smith","K","3456main","Orlando","FL","45235"), 
    ("2","Amaya","Williams","L","123Orange","Newark","NJ","27656"),("3","Alchemy","Davis","P","Warners","Sanjose","CA","34789")])
    .toDF(schema=['key','firstName','lastName','middleName','addressLine','city','state','zipCode'])

df.show()

catalog=''.join('''{
    "table":{"namespace":"emp_data","name":"emp_info"},
    "rowkey":"key",
    "columns":{
    "key":{"cf":"rowkey","col":"key","type":"string"},
    "fName":{"cf":"person","col":"firstName","type":"string"},
    "lName":{"cf":"person","col":"lastName","type":"string"},
    "mName":{"cf":"person","col":"middleName","type":"string"},
    "addressLine":{"cf":"address","col":"addressLine","type":"string"},
    "city":{"cf":"address","col":"city","type":"string"},
    "state":{"cf":"address","col":"state","type":"string"},
    "zipCode":{"cf":"address","col":"zipCode","type":"string"}
            }
    }'''.split())
#Writing
print("Writing into HBase")
df.write\
  .options(catalog=catalog)\
  .format(data_source_format)\
  .save()
#Reading
print("Readig from HBase")
df = sqlc.read\
         .options(catalog=catalog)\
         .format(data_source_format)\
         .load()

print("Program Ends")
```

Error Message:

Writing into HBase
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/mnt/c/Codefiles/pyspark_test.py", line 36, in 
df.write
File "/home/aditya/spark-3.1.2-bin-
hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line
1107, in save
File "/home/aditya/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-
src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in **call**
File "/home/aditya/spark-3.1.2-bin-
hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in
deco
File "/home/aditya/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-
src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
o63.save.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)

Answer (score 0):

check if java is installed and Java_home is set in the env variables.

Comment: You should see how do I write a good answer [answer].